# Vertically center images with flexbox

Tags: html, css, flexbox, centering

How do I vertically center these pairs of images?

I've searched everywhere and tried the `align-items: center` property with no success.

```css
.first {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.first img {
  width: 580px;
  height: 50vh;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.second img {
  padding-top: 2px;
  width: auto;
  height: 290px;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <img src="https://sarahannephoto.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/devyn_015.jpg?w=1008" alt="">
</div>

<div class="second">
  <img src="http://preen.inquirer.net/files/2016/05/preen-emily-oberg-complex-e1463660455785.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/64123ccb4f9358207ae32b94646138ca/tumblr_ni9bysrHCt1sh9i3lo1_1280.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/jsxor8a1/

EDIT:

I don't know if this is the right way but it fixed it. I added a margin-top: 25vh; to the top of the first image and that positioned it perfectly in the center.

```css
.first {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
}

.first img {
  margin-top: 25vh;
  width: 580px;
  height: 25vh;
}

.second {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.second img {
  padding-top: 2px;
  width: 290px;
  height: 25vh;
}
```

```html
<div class="first">
  <img src="https://sarahannephoto.files.wordpress.com/2015/01/devyn_015.jpg?w=1008" alt="">
</div>

<div class="second">
  <img src="http://preen.inquirer.net/files/2016/05/preen-emily-oberg-complex-e1463660455785.jpg" alt="">
  <img src="https://68.media.tumblr.com/64123ccb4f9358207ae32b94646138ca/tumblr_ni9bysrHCt1sh9i3lo1_1280.jpg" alt="">
</div>
```

Comment: Um, `vertical-align` maybe?

Comment: Vertically center them on the page?

Comment: margin and padding should not be use with flexbox.

Comment: @GabrielPozo, with your edited solution the images appear centered, but they also lose their aspect ratio. Not sure that's what you want.